# Нужно получить значение из текста регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Из вот этого `\"UNIQ\":\"3d562467-9f12-4b8b-b93f-637fddf534f3g4e4\"` нужно получить `3d562467-9f12-4b8b-b93f-637fddf534f3g4e4`. Использую регулярку

```
preg_match_all('/\\\"UNIQ\\\":\\\"(.*?)\\\"', $rrr, $matches);
```

Результата ноль. Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: Это же вроде json-строка, зачем тут регулярка?

Answer (score 2):

Показываю один раз:

```
$text = '\"UNIQ\":\"3d562467-9f12-4b8b-b93f-637fddf534f3g4e4\"';

$json = json_decode('{' . stripcslashes($text) . '}', TRUE);

var_dump($json['UNIQ']);
```

Несмотря на то, что кажется громоздким, будет работать быстрее регулярок.

Comment: а слона то я и не приметил)

Answer (score 1):

Вам подойдет следующая регулярка:

`\\"UNIQ\\":\\"([a-z\d-]*)\\"$`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если убрать экранирующие символы из исходной строки, тогда:

`"UNIQ":"([a-z\d-]*)"$`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, нормально работает и моя, просто закрыть шаблон забыл)

Comment: @Сергей, можете сделать проще воспользовавшись следующей регуляркой, вот она: `/UNIQ(?:\\":?){2}\K[^\\]+/`, [`демо`](https://regex101.com/r/0jHpjj/1)

Comment: Не думаю, что это проще. Для меня это вообще тарабарщина.) Но всё равно спасибо.